Inconsistency on Heaviside Derivative
I've been stuck while trying to redo some calculations of a paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.13267) and thought some of you might help. Essentially what I'm trying to do is calculate:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d \tilde{\epsilon}(x)}{dh}
\end{equation}
where $\frac{1}{\tilde{\epsilon} (x)} = \int{g_s(x-x')}\epsilon(x')^{-1} dx'$, $\epsilon(x) = \epsilon_1 + (\epsilon_2 - \epsilon_1)\Theta(x-h)$, with $\Theta(x)$ being the usual Heaviside Function, and $g_s(x)$ is some localized distribution that goes to a Dirac delta as $s\rightarrow 0$ (but it does not matter much now).
The paper goes and says that:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d \tilde{\epsilon}(x)}{dh} = -\tilde{\epsilon}^2 (\epsilon_1^{-1}-\epsilon_2^{-1})g_s(x-h)
\end{equation}
But what I find is that:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d \tilde{\epsilon}(x)}{dh} = -\tilde{\epsilon}^2\left(\frac{\epsilon_2 - \epsilon_1}{\epsilon(h)^2}\right)g_s(x-h)
\end{equation}
which is somewhat of a problem because $\epsilon(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=h$ and if I use the definition that $\Theta(0) = 1$ I still don't get the same result as the paper.
Does any one have a light to shine on this?

I found a way to get the same answers as the paper and was about to delete this question but thought it would be best to share my solution in the spirit of discussion:
The solution is idiotically simple, just rewrite $\frac{1}{\tilde{\epsilon}(x)}$ as:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\tilde{\epsilon}(x)} = \frac{1}{\epsilon_1} + \left(\frac{1}{\epsilon_2}-\frac{1}{\epsilon_1}\right)\Theta(x-h)
\end{equation}
That's it.
